# Linking Work Items from TFS to Visual Studo

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add work items from TFS to Visual Studio in the below hierarchy as they are in TFS. Anyone know how to do it?

```
- EPIC
   - Feature
     - Requirement
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean from TFS to VS? what did you try and you didn't a success?

Comment: In the query editor in VS in the column options there is no way that I have found to sort the work items from TFS in the same format that TFS is. For example in TFS there is 1 EPIC work item that has 2 features and each feature has its requirements or projects. when looking at my work items in VS there is no structure to  how the work items are listed. its either ASC or DESC there is no group by epic persay.

Answer (score 1):

The My Work panel in Visual Studio does not support any hierarchy view. It is a small and simple section with the brief work items description. Just try to imagine a query result with 10 child levels in that window ))

You have to use the Work Items panel and the Queries section.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not available at present.

If you use the new work item tracking with Visual Studio 2017 and above, you may have noticed that work items now **open in a browser window** by default.

To ensure compatibility with the new process customization capabilities, new controls and the new Work item form options, just you keep Visual Studio open work items in the browser.

So we encourage users to track work items in web portal. Work items in Visual Studio is used to do some simply track. There is no structure to how the work items are listed. Your requirement could not be achieved now. Sorry for any inconvenience.